# What is the gRPC++ equivalent of the Go context.Background()?

Tags: c++, go, grpc

If I understand `::grpc::ServerContext` correctly, there is no way to obtain an empty one.

So is the idea that all my methods should work with `::grpc::ClientContext` instead?

If not, what is the equivalent of the Go `context.Background()` call, that allows me to fetch a context for command line utilities and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [go context documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Background) ,

> `context.Background()` returns a non-nil, empty Context. It is never canceled, has no values, and has no deadline. It is typically used by the main function, initialization, and tests, and as the top-level Context for incoming requests.

And indeed if you inspect the source code you will find out that a background context is an instante of an empty context, which will return no deadline.

Now back to C++, by inspecting [the source](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/cpp/client/client_context.cc) you can see that context is built in a similar fashion and several examples illustrate that an empty `ClientContext` [can be used](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/d86acba1daa56ff4867280cb5b4e238d58869ced/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_client.cc#L55).

Furthermore, checking https://grpc.github.io/blog/deadlines illustrates that for C++ you can set a deadline like this:

```
ClientContext context;
time_point deadline = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + 
    std::chrono::milliseconds(100);
context.set_deadline(deadline);
```

Which to me means that the equivalent of `context.Background()` in C++ is just and empty context:

```
ClientContext context;
```

Also this should apply to `ServerContext` too.
I hope this can help you!